AWS Network Load Balancer - routing based on source IP
We have a scenario where from AWS NLB, we have to route traffic to specific target groups, based on the source ip of the request. e.g;
if request is from A then NLB should route traffic to target groups A1 and A2
if request is from B then NLB should route traffic to target groups B1 and B2
I know, above can be achieved if we use AWS ALB but we must use AWS NLB because we have to use TLS and with ALB we can not use TLS.
If someone can guide on this.

What do you mean you cannot use TLS with ALB? ALB supports TLS 1.3

What I mean is, I am not able to assigned target groups to ALB, if the target group is on  protocol TLS port 443. If the target group is of HTTPS and port 443 then ALB is able to accept it but not with TLS/443. That is the reason we have to use NLB and my above question.

Can someone help with above question please?
